# Proving $\tan A=\frac{1-\cos B}{\sin B} \;\implies\; \tan 2A=\tan B$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\tan A=\dfrac{1-\cos B}{\sin B}$, prove that $\tan 2A=\tan B$.

My effort:

Here

$$\tan A=\frac{1-\cos B}{\sin B}$$
Now

$$\begin{align}\text{L.H.S.} &=\tan 2A \\[4pt]
&=\frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan ^2A} \\[6pt]
&=\frac{(2-2\cos B)\over\sin B}{1-\frac{(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin^2 B}}
\end{align}$$

On simplification from here, I could not get the required R.H.S.

Comment: Multiply top and bottom by $\sin^2B$, expand the denominator in which you replace $\sin^2B$ by $1-\cos^2B$. Factor and simplify.

Comment: $1-(1-\cos B)^2/\sin^2B=(\sin^2B-1-\cos^2B+2\cos B)/\sin^2B$ and then remember that $\sin^2B-1=-\cos^2B$.

Comment: All you have to do is write tan A = tan(B/2) and then say it implies, tan 2A = tan B

Comment: It seem that you got stuck on the denominator. Proceed with it as follows. 
$$1-\frac{(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin B} = \frac{\sin^2B}{\sin^2B}-\frac{(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin^2 B}= \frac{\sin^2 B-(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin^2B}$$

Can you proceed from here? Hint: $\sin^2 B + \cos^2 B=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proceed in this way:

$$\tan A=\frac{1-\cos B}{\sin B}=\frac{2\sin^2 \frac{B}{2}}{2\sin\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}}=\frac{\sin\frac{B}{2}}{\cos\frac{B}{2}}=\tan \frac{B}{2}$$

And hence comparing, we can write that $A=n\pi + \frac{B}{2}$ where $n$ is any integer.

So we can say that $2A=2n\pi + B \Rightarrow \tan 2A = \tan(2n\pi + B) = \tan B$

Hence proved.

Comment: could you please explain me  about the part from"And hence comparing.........




I could not understand it...

Comment: @Iaamuseruser Its a kind of empirical formula. If $\tan x= \tan y$ then $x=n\pi +y$. You can check this by taking different values of $x,y$. And after that, I just multiplied both sides of the equation by $2$ and then took the $\tan$ on both sides.

Comment: @ SchrodingersCat, you have written, "And hence comparing" but comparing with what?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, $B=0$ needs special handling!  Otherwise its my own way:)

Comment: @Iaamuseruser By that "And hence comparing", I just compared the R.H.S. with the L.H.S. Nothing else.... No need to stress on that in particular.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Note that the given expression implies:

$\tan(A)=\frac{1-\cos(B)}{\sin(B)} \cdot \frac{1+\cos(B)}{1+\cos(B)}=\frac{\sin(B)}{1+\cos(B)}$

Therefore

$\tan(2A)=\frac{2\tan(A)}{1-\tan^2(A)}=\frac{2\frac{\sin(B)}{1+\cos(B)}}{1-\left(\frac{1-\cos(B)}{\sin(B)}\cdot \frac{\sin(B)}{1+\cos(B)}\right)}=\frac{2\sin(B)}{2\cos(B)}=\tan(B)$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right road.... Continuing calculation,
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{2-2\cos B}{\sin B}}{1-\frac{(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin^2 B}}&=\frac{\frac{2-2\cos B}{\sin B}}{\frac{\sin^2 B -1+2\cos B-\cos^2 B }{\sin^2 B}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2-2\cos B}{\sin B}}{\frac{\sin^2 B -\sin^2 B -\cos^2 B+2\cos B-\cos^2 B }{\sin^2 B}}\\
&=\frac{\frac{2-2\cos B}{\sin B}}{\frac{2\cos B(1-\cos B)}{\sin^2 B}}\\
&=\frac{2\sin^2 B(1-\cos B)}{2\cos B\sin B(1-\cos B)}\\
&=\frac{\sin B}{\cos B}\\
&=\tan B
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from your last step,
    $$
    LHS=\frac{\frac{2-2\cos B}{\sin B}}{1-\frac{(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin^2B}}\\
       =\frac{\frac{2-2\cos B}{\sin B}}{\frac{\sin^2B-(1-\cos B)^2}{\sin^2B}} \\
       =\frac{2-2\cos B}{\frac{\sin^2B-1-\cos^2B+2\cos B}{\sin B}}
      $$
and then use that $1=\sin^2+\cos^2B$ to get
  $$
 LHS= \frac{2(1-\cos B)(\sin B)}{\sin^2B-\sin^2B-\cos^2B-\cos^2B+2\cos B}\\
    =\frac{2(1-\cos B)(\sin B)}{2\cos B(1-\cos B)}\\
    =\frac{\sin B}{\cos B}=\tan B=RHS
$$